# Problems with foreign language encoding in CSV in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a VB.Net script saving a CSV from a database which contains Japanese, Chinese, Korean, and English characters.

The file opens fine in a plain text editor, but in Excel it shows either the "question mark" character, other apparently randomly characters, or dashes. It does this no matter which encoding format I choose when importing the data.

The code I have to open the file looks like this

```
  Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=notifications.csv")
  Dim utf8 As New UTF8Encoding()
  Dim strW As New IO.StreamWriter("\windows\temp\notifications.csv", False, utf8)
  strW.Write(utf8.GetPreamble())
```

**EDIT: ** Apparently this only happens in Excel 2011 for Mac

Comment: `"The file opens in a plain text editor"` This indicates that the problem is in Excel, your code is already doing the right thing.

Comment: @Joel [It could be the editor guessing the encoding, and botching the job.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel on Mac has severe deficiencies in this department. CSV files are assumed to be encoded in [MacRoman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) – any encoding preamble is simply ignored. As far as I’m aware there’s no workaround for this, you *have* to encode the CSV file accordingly, or use the file open dialog in Excel to select the appropriate encoding.

Comment: The strange thing is even if I select UTF-8 from the encoding menu when I import the data, I get "------" instead of the correct characters